# Object of certain constructions

Tags: syntax, terminology, verbs, cognates, grammatical-object

I am sure you have all come across constructions such as these:

> She slept a long sleep
>
> He lived a productive life.

These verbs are traditionally intransitive verbs, and yet here are transitive. However, the semantic role of their objects (I take it that their objects are of the same semantic role) is completely different from the semantic role of most objects (e.g. "ball" in "He kicked a ball"). What is the semantic role of the objects here? And how come these verbs - which are virtually always intransitive, to the extent that I am not willing to consider them ambitransitive (seeing as such verbs tend to have both several transitive and intransitive uses) - take an object here? Is there a name for these constructions?

Comment: I don't know what these are called in traditional English grammars.  In classical Greek and Latin, they are often called cognate accusatives or internal objects; however, this phenomenon exists in many languages, even those unrelated to English, Greek, or Latin.

Comment: In my experience they are called 'extent NPs'. Their syntactic status is somewhat problematic since they generally differ quite sharply from objects. One solution is to admit them as objects only where they can be made subject of a passive, as in _We will have to walk the last few miles_ ~ _The last few miles will have to be walked_. In your examples, it all depends on whether we can say _?A long sleep was slept_ / _?A productive life was lived_.

Comment: "Matchmaker, Matchmaker, make me a match, / Find me a find, catch me a catch." Walk the walk, talk the talk... Maybe the issue here is less about the fact that "sleep" and "life" are rarely transitive ("find," "catch," "walk," and "talk" are more often), and more about a structure in which a verb and noun of the same word are paired.

Comment: I was taught in grammar school that that construction was called a [Cognate Object](https://www.google.com/search?q=cognate+object). It reminds me of the small verb plus object constructions, like _give a push, take a piss, have fun,_ where the object is effectively the predicate. Small verbs like _take, go, get, have, give,_ etc are either auxiliaries taking on new constructions or verbs caught in the act of becoming auxiliaries.